# Rational function has no expression where zero set is contained in another

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We take $X = V(xy-zw)$ for $V(xy-zw)$ the set of points in $\mathbb A^4_{x,y,z,w}$ in which $xy-zw = 0$.

Given this, is it always the case that the rational function $f = x/z \in k(X)$ cannot be expressed as $g/h$ for $g,h \in k[X]$ with $V_X(h) \subseteq V_X(y,z)$? I was thinking contradiction would perhaps be the way to go, but can't quite seem to figure it out.

Here we use $k$ to denote an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.

Comment: What if $y=0$ but $z\neq 0$, such as points $(x:0:1:w)$? Then $f$ is regular there. The issue is only when $h$ is zero at a point where $z$ is not zero, so $V_X(h)\subsetneq V_X(z)$ with proper containment